# Upgrading to v3.0

Tags: highcharts

I have updated from Highcharts 2.3.5 to Highcharts 3.0 and found some problems:

1) The printer button (exporting) - has disappeared ?

2) Is the export icon changed it's size? as I have added new custome image clickable
buttons - which should change their size too

See image attached:

[image]

Comment: Found the print button hidden - can I still show a print button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mention of this in the release announcement

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/54-highcharts-3-0-released

Scroll to the bottom.